# Extracting values of controls in each row of a table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Please take a look here :(Updated)
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/10/)

I am trying to create a comma `,` and pipe `|` separated string of the values of the controls in each row of the table.  Each control value separated by a comma and each row separated by a pipe I am doing so using this piece of code..

```
$("#btnsave").click(function () {
    var result = "";
    $("#field tr").each(function (iRow, row) {
        $("td input", row).each(function (iField, field) {
            result += $(field).val() + ",";
        });
        result = result + "|";
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

The problem with this code is that it excludes DropDown. And also I would like to include the row number which is shown in the first column. 
Although I am using this code right now I do not understand much of it. Can someone explain this code to me, I am a noob in Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Adding *dropdowns*, by which I think you mean `select` elements, is fairly easy, by just changing `$('td input', row)` to `$('td input, td select', row)` instead.

I've created an example (http://jsbin.com/garohure/1/edit) which includes the first column in the output as well:

```
function tableToString(){
    var rows = [];

    $("#field tr").each(function (iRow, row) {

        var cells = [],
            firstTd = $(row).find('td').first();

        cells.push( firstTd.text() );

        $(row).find('input,select').each(function (iField, field) {
            cells.push( $(field).val() );
        });

        rows.push( cells.join('|') );
    });

   return rows.join(',<br>');
}
```

My function is a bit different, as I tried to make it a bit clearer to what is happening. I also collect all values in an array first, join it to a string and then save it.

The logic here is:

- get all rows/`TR`s in the table and loop through them
- get the first cell's value and the value of all input and select fields in that row
- join those values and save them in the rows array
- when done, join all values in the rows array and return them

Btw having this as an extra function instead of doing this all in your event callback lets you easily execute it from somewhere else (the console for testing for example).

Comment: I added a header row to your table and I am facing a problem. The final string includes first cell of header column. Take a look http://jsbin.com/garohure/2/edit

Comment: your answer is close but , what if there are other elements in certain cells like image button etc I would like data from TextBox and Dropdown only. 
Also what if I want `.text()` value of dropdown instead of `.val`

Comment: Use `thead` and `tbody` tags in your table, then only select rows in tbody. As for getting the values, do `input[type=text]` to be more explicit. Not sure though what you mean by doing `.text()`on the drop downs though. Can you explain? - I've updated the example: http://jsbin.com/garohure/5/edit